# How to send email to external users without using SP 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, send-email

I have a requirement to send email to the external users using Jquery but I can not use the SharePoint 2010 workflow.

Kindly let me know with the solution except SharePoint 2010 workflow.

I have been through a few solutions but all of the suggests to use SP 2010 workflow which i can not.

Let me know with the possible solutions for **"JQuery - Send Email to External User without 2010 Workflow"**

Comment: Is it SharePoint Online or OnPremise?

Comment: I have to provide the solution on both Online and OnPremise. The first step is to give on Online and second release will include the OnPremise solution.

Answer (score 0):

You create an azure function on Azure cloud. In that function you write C# code to send emails. You write that azure function takes parameters from email,subject,body, toemail..etc see this link to [create Azure function App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal). You create an http service c# azure function . [here the guide for creating the c# http trigger fucntion](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-azure-functions-for-sharepoint-operations-using-managed-csom/)

you can call this azure function as a service in your JQuery ajax call and also in 2013 workflow through Call HTTP service action to send email.

Comment: I think this is like making an ajax call. Am I right ?

can you provide me any other alternative ? anything which uses only Jquery or JavaScript ?

Comment: You don't have inbuilt methods in JQuery or Ajax  to send emails. you have to code in c# or any other language and expose that as a service and call that service in JQuery or javascript. easy way is to create azure function as it is already a hosted service. you no need to struggle much.

Comment: ok. i will check this solution